# Why does only one method of linking .css and .html files work in my program?

Tags: css, xhtml, aptana

I recently started learning the ropes of web programming, and while reading a book I was shown two ways of linking an .html file to a .css file.

Method 1:

```
<link rel="examplesheet" href="myexamplesheet.css" type="text/css"
 media="screen" />
```

Method 2:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen"> 
@import url(examplesheet.css);
</style>
```

They should both work, as some questions have [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321478/whats-the-difference-between-these-two-methods-of-linking-a-html-page-to-a-css), but Method 1 isn't working for my program, even though Method 2 works fine.

My program is quite simple. It looks like this:

```
<title> Title Site</title>

<link rel="canvas" href="canvas.css" type="text/css"
media="screen" />

<style type="text/css" media="screen"> 
@import url(canvas.css);
</style>

<p> We have black text.</p>
<p class="green"> And then we have Green Text.</p>

<p class="warning"> Warning. Warning. Warning.</p>
```

If Method 1 is the only one there, the text won't show properly. In Internet Explorer, it just showed the default text. But in Firefox and Chrome, it actually showed an error with Method 1:

> XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
>   Location: file:///C:/Users/Zolani/AppData/Local/Temp/sample.xhtml
>   Line Number 3, Column 1:

I'm not sure why this only shows up on those two browsers. A [web page](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningcss/f/css_import_link.htm) detailing the differences talked about putting it in the head of the text. I tried that, using the "head" tag, and it still didn't work.

Now I could just go on with Method 2 and live happily with my programs, but I'd still like to know why Method 1 doesn't seem to work properly. Any ideas?

*Note: I'm using xhtml instead of html.*

Comment: Your example is not valid XHTML, it is missing a doctype, and at the very least the html, head and body elements.

Comment: @Neil You're right. I just added those and it works on the other browsers, now. Assumed those were arbitrary since it seemed to work on IE without them. Appreciate the tip.

Comment: IE was probably reading it as HTML rather than XHTML.

Answer (score 5):

The `rel` attribute must be `stylesheet` in order for the browser to interpret it as a stylesheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="canvas.css" type="text/css"
media="screen" />
```

**[Teh Specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-xhtml2-20030506/mod-styleSheet.html#sec_18.1.3.)**

Comment: So "stylesheet" is a specific keyword?

Comment: @Zolani13: It is. Link to specs added.